# Is there an elegant way to avoid code duplication with Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm looking for the best way to handle this case:

```
if (/* condition */) {
  /* do something */
} else {
  asyncFunc().then(/* do the same thing */);
}
```

I though of using a stored callback but this is not very readable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any if/else where you'll be doing the same thing in both branches, you should put repeated code outside of the conditional. This can be done easily with `async/await` like this:

```
if (!/* condition */) {
    await asyncFunc();
}
/* do something either immediately or after the asyncFunc resolves */
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your common code to function

```
function someThing() {
/* do something */
}
if (/* condition */) {
  someThing();
} else {
  asyncFunc().then(someThing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small object that handles your statements for you, which also contain the functions you need. This was you can recycle/append any functionality you need and expand whenever you need to.

```
    let App = {
        process: function (obj) {
            if (obj.param) {
                App.funcA();
            } else {
                App.asyncThing().then((res) => { App.funcA(res) });
            }
        },
        asyncThing: function () { /*..*/ },
        funcA: function () { /*...*/ },
    }
    App.process({param: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert first case to promise

```
(YourCondition ? Promise.resolve(someValue) : asyncFunc()).then(v => ...)
```